# Setting content-type to application/json

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-functions

I have this C# code in my Azure function:

```
var data = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var request = await GetSubmissions.PostAsync("url", data);

if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var response = req.CreateResponse(request.StatusCode);
    await response.WriteStringAsync(content);
    return response;
}
```

This receives data from an API call, and then returns it as response from that Azure function. All is good and I can see it being returned in Postman just fine, but I need to change the content type to JSON within the response as it is coming in as text.

As shown in this screenshot:

[image]

What can I try next?

Comment: There seem to exist a bunch of [WriteAsJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httpresponsedataextensions.writeasjsonasync?view=azure-dotnet) overloads you should use instead of WriteStringAsync.

Comment: How about below:  

return new ContentResult()
                    {
                        Content = contentYouWantToreturn,
                        ContentType = "application/json"
                    };

Comment: `var response = ` what is the type of the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the response header:

```cs
response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Another option (though less preferable one) would be to deserialize the response and then serialize it back with `WriteAsJsonAsync`.